# Jquery return default input value when focusing out

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, search, input

I have a search input with a default value "Search for".

[image]

When I focus on the input the value clears.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').focus(function() {           
        if($(this).val() == "Search for") 
        $(this).val('');
    });
});
```

If you don't type anything to search, what would be a good way to return the default "Search for" value when focusing out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a [watermark plugin](http://updatepanel.net/2009/04/17/jquery-watermark-plugin/) if you're already using jQuery?  Why the need for a reinvented wheel?

If you must do this on your own,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').focus(function() {           
        if($(this).val() == "Search for") 
        $(this).val('');
    }).focusout(function() {
      if($(this).val() === '')
         $(this).val('Search for');
    });
});
```

Comment: Up vote for the code, seems a bit much to add a plugin for 4 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks the code works! I agree with matt. The plugin is a bit much.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a quick bit of code for you. It will use the jQuery data method to save a bool indicating that the user has typed something. If the person doesn't type anything, it'll show the text again.

```
$("#search").blur(function() {
    if (!$(this).data('hasTyped')) {
        $(this).val('Search for');
    }
}).keyup(function() {
    $(this).data('hasTyped', this.value.length);
}).focus(function() {
    if (!$(this).data('hasTyped')) {
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathon/dbbBh/

Comment: 1up for example! thanks! Your code however has 1 disadvantage. On clearing the user input, "Search for" won't reappear.

Comment: :) Sorted - just changed setting the data to the length of the value, rather than `true`. If the value has zero length, `hasTyped` is set as a falsey value

Answer (score 1):

what about using focos out

```
$("#search").focusout(function() {
$(this).val('Search for');
});
```

or blur

```
    $('#search').focus(function(){
// focus logic goes here


}).blur(function(){

  $(this).val('Search for');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

What about the same but "inverted"?

```
$('#search').blur(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "" ) { 
        $(this).val('Search for');
    }
});
```

Comment: good idea but I still need to clear the default value on blur

Comment: What about the case where the user first clicks into the search box?